# apache crash with exec in php

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, php, php5, server-crashes

i am try to convert some file with exec in php and get the return . i do this and this is work so successfully but if i run it for more than 10 times, the webserver (wampserver) get crash and i must restart server to continue ?

the only thing is unusually it's in my processes in taskmanager . if the convert files be successfully "cmd.exe" closed automatically after that, but if convert get worse the cmd.exe not closed and it remain in processes and i force it to close with "end process" but wampserver can not work until i restart it completely ?

is there any idea about solve apache or php or server problem ?
System : wampserver version 2.0 on windows xp and 2003 server .

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is a problem with how many requests it serves. The key, then(failing fixing the tool) is to restart the apache process after 9 times. Have you checked out the MaxRequestsPerChild setting under either prefork.c or worker.c? From httpd.conf:

```
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
```

Comment: i found this in my httpd.conf at C:\xampp\apache\conf\ it is : "MaxRequestsPerChild 0", i must change it ?

Comment: I would. A setting of 0 means that it is unlimited. And if it turns out to be a bad idea because it dies(faster than it already does) or something similar, then you can change it back.